# Jacobi Identity of structure constants of ${\rm SU}(N)$ group

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, lie-algebra

I am dealing with an exercise about the  ${\rm SU}(N)$ group. I have shown that the structure constants are given by

[image]

I am now asked to show that the following Jacobi identity is true:

[image]

The first thing I did was simply plugging them into the Jacobi Identity, but at some point I get stuck and have the feeling that it will lead me back to where I started. I am now considering to use the fact that the f are fully antisymmetric, whereas the $d$ are fully symmetric. Can someone maybe help me get on the right track?

Comment: Due [diligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_superalgebra#Properties).

Comment: Please do not post formulae as screenshots, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen that identity before. The only think that comes to mind is to try taking a trace with an extra generator of the identity
$$
[T_1,\{T_2, T_3\}]+ \{T_2,[T_3, T_1]\}- \{T_3,[T_1, T_2]\}=0
$$
that holds for any matrices $T_1,T_2, T_3$.

Answer (score 0):

You can generalize the result to any Lie algebra.

I would recommand that, on one hand, you do the direct calculation of $[X_a, [X_b, X_c]] + [X_b, [X_c, X_a]] + [X_c, [X_a, X_b]]$ for $X_a,X_b,X_c \in SU(n)$.
On the other hand, you should do the same calculation, but by this time using the structure constants (Hint: commutators).

Then, you would just have to compare the two expressions you get, and you should obtain the desired result.